# are there any plants that are known to keep termites and ants away

Tags: plant-recommendations, insects, ants

I know we can bait the ant or termite or cockroach with boric acid or baking soda powder mixed with sugar and kill them off.

Or we can mix vinegar with baking soda powder and pore over the ant's colony or pour near the places where ants or termites enters the building the smell prevents them from coming in.

Or use calcium and draw a line ... the carbonate stops the ant atleast.

So I'm wondering is there any plant that releases some smell which will keep ants,termites or mosquitoes or cockroaches away from the building.

Comment: I've seen claims that tansy  (Tanacetum vulgare) will repel ants. I have my doubts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tansy

Comment: Thanks , I will have a look

Comment: What part of the world are you in ?  In Australia they have effective termite treatments for buildings.

Comment: South asia mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following plants are known to keep Ant/Termites away

- Chrysanthemum
- Mint
- Rose mary
- Lavender
- Garlic
- Basil
- tansy

Following plants are known to keep mosquitoes away

- Rose Mary
- Lemon grass
- Marigold
- lavender
- Floss flower
- Catnip
- Sage

Following plants are known to keep snakes away

- Marigold
- Holy
- Snake
- Lemon Grass
- Onion and Garlic
- Pink agapanthus
- Mugwort
- Cactus
- Basil
- sage

Comment: Do you have any citations?  Personally, I don't believe that any of this is true.  The last university research I read said that if there is any effect, it would be because the pests are more attracted to the fragrant plants.  And I can personally vouch that in our garden Basil, Mint and Lavender have no effect on any pests.  They are pest ridden themselves.

Comment: Aromas are known to attract as well as repel pests

Comment: Basil , mint and lavender repels flies.If you place that strategically in your home. You can repel flies from your home